# how to build automatic number with stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have data like this in item table

```
Tabel siswa                          Tabel jurusan             Tabel Penjurusan
id_siswa nama nilai tes id_jurusan   id_jurusan id_fakultas  nama         id id_siswa id_jurusan option ket
1         A     6         01           01             04     Sipil       1    1        01         1    lULUS
2         B     7         02           02             04     Mesin       2    1        02         2    TIDAK LULUS    
3         C     8         01           03             09     Sastra      3    1        03         3    TIDAK LULUS
4         D     6         03                                             4    2        01         1    LULUS
5         E     7         02                                             5    2        02         2    TIDAK LULUS
                                                                         6    2        03         3    TIDAK LULUS
```

and i want to make otomatis number with format like this

> year_kode fakultas_kode jurusan_nomor(yyffjj0000)

nomor is number between 0001-9999 and sorting by value max "Nilai tes"

and my query like this

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE kd_mahasiswa (kode int(10), tgl_daftar date, nama_jurusan varchar(225), nama_fakultas varchar(225))

BEGIN
  DECLARE kunci varchar(20);
  DECLARE urut  varchar(20);

  SET kunci = CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(YEAR,@tgl_daftar)) '+'
                    UPPER(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(@nama_jurusan)) '+'
                UPPER(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(@nama_fakultas));

  SELECT urut = ISNULL(MAX(RIGHT(kode,4)),0) + 1 FROM siswa, penjurusan, jurusan, fakultas WHERE penjurusan.kode = siswa.kode
AND jurusan.id_jurusan = penjurusan.id_penjurusan AND fakultas.id_fakultas = jurusan.id_fakultas order by nilai_tes,uang_gedung DESC

  SET urut = RIGHT('000' + @urut,4);

  SET kunci = CONCAT(kunci,urut);

  INSERT INTO siswa VALUES(kunci,@tgl_daftar,@nama_jurusan, @nama_fakultas)
END
```

i try that query but procedure error

```
  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@kunci varchar(20)
  DECLARE @urut  varchar(20)

  SET @kunci = CONVERT(varch' at line 4
```

I used Mysql..

Please, help me solve this problem?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `DECLARE` user-defined variables, names of user-defined variables start with `@` character.

Procedure variable names do *not* begin with an `@` character.

If you want to use user-defined variables, drop the DECLARE statements. If you want to use procedure variables, drop the `@` character from the variable references.

Note that statements within a procedure need to be terminated with a semicolon. And the `+` operator is numeric addition, not string concatenation.

For example:

```
    DECLARE kunci VARCHAR(20) ;
    SET urut = RIGHT(CONCAT('000',urut),4);
    SET kunci = CONCAT(kunci,urut);
```

There can be name collisions between procedure variables, procedure arguments and column names. MySQL resolves these collisions by giving procedure variables precedence over procedure arguments and columns.

If you want to assign the value of an expression to a user defined variable in a SELECT statement, you need to use the `:=` assignment operator...

```
    SELECT @urut := expr 
                 ^^
```

To assign return the result from a SELECT into a procedure variable, you can use the `SELECT ... INTO` form of the SELECT statement:

```
    SELECT expr INTO urut FROM ...
                ^^^^
```

(With the `SELECT... INTO`, if the query returns more than one row, MySQL will throw an error; you can ensure the query returns at most one row by adding a `LIMIT 1` clause at the end of the SELECT statement.